# Mapping a domain name

Tags: urls

I am trying to map a domain name I purchased:

```
http://name.com
```

to a specific url in wordpress with a path:

```
http://ip/wordpress/page/
```

Multisite configuration is installed.
Is that possible to be done?

Comment: You have an existing page on a WordPress site you want to map to a different domain, is that right? That's not what multisite is for.

Comment: Right now I have a wordpress site with IP address only. I need to map this IP address to the domain I purchased.

Comment: This is WP unrelated, configure your hosting properly or ask your provider for help